# better approach to this jquery/code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want these brackets to slide out and wrap the word on hover. Then off hover collapse down to their original state.

Better cross-browser approach?

HTML (formatted for readability):

```
<h2 id="title">
    <span id="bracket1">[</span>
    <span id="bracket2">]</span>
CUBIX</h2>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#title").hover(function(){
    $("#bracket2").animate({ left: "170px" });
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/afjHh

Comment: Please add your code in the question.

Comment: You're already using jQuery - it's as crossbrowser as it gets. Yoy can determine width dynamically tho

Comment: *"Better cross-browser approach?"* Which problem do you experience with the code you have? If there is no problem, this question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: (Comment from @Brian S, in suggested edit) [something I whipped up](http://jsfiddle.net/hPEUV/). It will animate in the way OP wanted regardless of the word's length. I chose 38 & 20px as arbitrarily appropriate values - they can be changed/calculated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I guess I would do something similar to this, if you want it to collapse back down.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrcmg

```
$( "#title" ).hover(
  function() {
    $("#bracket2").stop(true, false).animate({ left: "170px" });
  }, function() {
    $("#bracket2").stop(true, false).animate({ left: "20px" });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly so far. The only thing left is the animation back

```
$("#title").hover(function(){
    $("#bracket2").animate({ left: "170px" });
}, function(){
    $("#bracket2").animate({ left: "20px" });
});
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAykb/)

A CSS only version can be achieved with [CSS transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

```
h2:hover span#bracket2 {
    left: 170px;
    -webkit-transition: left 1s;
    -moz-transition: left 1s;
    transition: left 1s;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LAykb/1/)